# can't assign character when while loop is done in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to find solution how to add '\0' at the end of string (array of characters in C ).
I already have array "number" which is generated from for loop.

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
char s[] = "123.45e-10";
while (s[i] != '\0') {
    if (isdigit(s[i]) && eFound == false) {
        number[j++] = s[i];
    }
    i++
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
i = 0;
while (isdigit(number[i])){
    i++;
}
printf("%d", i);
number[i] = 'b';
```

I have no compile errors, but when running program visual studio says

> "Debug Assertion Fail".

Why is this not possible to do in C?

EDIT (whole code added):

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996) //disables crt warnings
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

double stof(char s[]);

int main(){
    char string[] = "123.45e-10";
    stof(string);

}

double stof(char s[]) {
    bool isNegative = false;
    bool eFound = false;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    char number[10];
    char potention[11];
    int dotPosition;


while (s[i] != '\0') {
    if (isdigit(s[i]) && eFound == false) {
        number[j++] = s[i];
    }
    else if (s[i] == '.') {
        dotPosition = i;
    }
    else if (s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'E')
        eFound = true;

    else if (s[i] == '-')
        isNegative = true;

    else if (eFound== true && isdigit(s[i])){
        potention[k++] = s[i];
    }
        i++;
}

i = 0;
while (isdigit(number[i])){
    i++;
}
printf("%d", i);
number[i] = 'b';


const int charSize = dotPosition;
int potentionN = atoi(potention);


char beforeDecimal[sizeof(number)];
char addedNulls[20];
int g = 0;
if (isNegative == true) {
    strncpy(beforeDecimal, number, dotPosition);
    int addNull = potentionN - sizeof(beforeDecimal);
    printf("%d", addNull);
    while (g < addNull) {
        addedNulls[g] = '0';
        g++;
    }
    printf("%d", strlen(addedNulls));
}


return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: What is `number`? Why withhold crucial information?

Comment: This code does not compile. There is no declaration of `number` or `eFound`, and no `asserts`. Can you [make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I haven't written C in some years. Is that a legal char[] declaration you have where you just assign it a string?

Comment: I have added whole code now, sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @GeniaS. Yes, initializing a `char` array from a string literal is perfectly legal.

Comment: @jamesdlin, thanks. I seem to recall doing some sort of wacky {'a', 'b', 'c'} business but as I said, it's been a while.

Comment: Fyi, you never terminate `addedNulls` while building it. You just populate a bunch of `'0'`, then assume `strlen` will work, using the wrong format specifier in the process. *Run this in a **debugger***.

Comment: This code is not finished, and the part I am asking is executed before it.

Comment: The string `number` is not null-terminated by the first loop.  That might matter.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this not possible to do in C?

Every computable answer can be found with a Turing-complete language.  Your question is more like, *where is the error in my code*?

In C, it's very important to ensure you read & write only to defined memory: those locations covered by your variables.  You're testing your input locations with

```
while (s[i] != '\0')
```

but nowhere do you ensure that you stay within the bounds of `number` and `potention`.  Especially here:

```
i = 0;
while (isdigit(number[i])){
    i++;
}
```

At no point do you write a nondigit to `number`.  Why should that loop ever end?

The instant fix is to initialize `number`:

```
char number[10] = {};
```

That causes the compiler to initialize the array with any elements inside `{}`, and the rest of it with zeros.  Since the initializer is empty, the whole array is filled with zeros.

That way, provided you don't fill `number` with digits, your while loop will terterminate.  A belt-and-suspenders solution is make double-sure:

```
i = 0;
while (i < sizeof(number) && isdigit(number[i])) {
    i++;
}
```

I haven't debugged your whole program; I haven't even compiled it.  The run-time error you're seeing suggests you're writing to undefined memory.  If you check the array bounds in each loop, you can avoid that particular problem and move on to the next one. ;-)